# Total possible combinations of primes

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I have been working on a problem as follows:
Do there exist 100 consecutive natural numbers none of which is prime?
I know that the answer is 'yes', by considering 101!, and noting the sequence 101! + 2, 101! + 3, ... , 101! + 101.

This approach generalises nicely by considering (n+1)!

However, whilst tacking this problem, I tried many different techniques.

The approach I was most interested in was the following intuition:
We know that the primes are much more spread out than occurring every n integers from knowledge beyond the problem. Since every number can be factorised uniquely into primes despite primes being rare, if we have a prime at least every 100 numbers, say, then we should surely be able to show that the number of possible combinations of primes exceeds the number of numbers that exist.

My problem is that I have found it hard to count the total number of combinations. 
For example, 
Say a prime occurs at least once every 100 numbers. Then there are at least N primes less than 100N. How many prime combinations can you make that are less than 100N? I'm hoping that I can get a result that exceeds 100N, and therefore we show that the primes cannot populate the natural numbers this densely.

Sorry for the long question! Just thought I'd give some background to my question.

Comment: The [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) might make you want to reword your question, but more significantly the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) tells you that every number from $2$ to $100N$ (or any other number) is either prime or a product of primes (possibly with repetition) in a unique way.

Comment: I know, but what I'm saying is: Suppose, for contradiction, that in fact in every interval of n consecutive integers there exists at least one prime.

Comment: Then intuitively this makes the primes a lot denser in the natural numbers than they actually are, so we should be able to contradict FTA somehow, namely by the combinations approach described

Answer (score 2):

All you need is that the density of prime numbers goes to $0$.  If there are fewer than $M = \lfloor N/100 \rfloor$ primes $\le N$, then at least one of the $M$ intervals $[1,100], [101, 200], \ldots, [100(M-1)+1, 100 M]$ has no primes.

Comment: How can I show that?

Comment: There are $M$ disjoint intervals.  If you took one prime from each interval, you'd have $M$ primes $\le N$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to show this is by the [divergence of sum of reciprocals of primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes). If the density of primes was a constant $k$, then the n-th prime $p_n \geq kn$. This will show that the sum diverges. This does not look like the easiest way of doing it though.

Edit: This is really a combinations approach in disguise due to how the divergence is proved from the zeta function.